# CrossVideo Gallery 6.6 dotnetnuke module

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm currently using CrossVideo Galery 6.6 with DotNetNuke (DNN). I'm looking at the IDs of HTML tags within a ViewList and I'm seeing something like

```
<table id="**dnn_ctr782_ViewTagList_ctl04_dlTag**" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
            <tr align="left">
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <a id="**dnn_ctr782_ViewTagList_ctl04_dlTag_lnkName_0**" class="Normal" target="_self" ... >.mp4(2)</a>
                    <a id="**dnn_ctr782_ViewTagList_ctl04_dlTag_lnkRss_0**" ... >
                    ...
```

This code snippet comes from the source code of the page at: http://dnnmodule.com/Modules/CrossVideoGallery/DNNVideoGalleryModule.aspx

I know the "782" portion of the id attribute pertains to the module id number. Can someone tell me what the “ctl05” pertains to? And is it stored within a table that I can access?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can get the entire name by using the code in the ascx file and assign it right to a variable in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
m_ClientIdPrefix = '<%=this.Control.ClientID %>'; // retruns dnn_ctr2586_ViewList_ctl02
</script>
```

All ids will be prefixed with this when HTML is responded from the server. Useful if you want to manipulate anything on the client side of DNN.